# How can I create a drag-and-drop component GUI builder using Swing?

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, gui-builder

I want to develop a program that creates Swing applications and whose Java source code is created side by side (e.g. drag a button and drop it onto frame whose source is to be created).

1. How much time it will take?
2. Should I use JInternalFrame or simple Frame?
3. How should I generate source code?  How does code get put into the .java file when I drag-and-drop a component?

Comment: *"How much time it will take?"*  For someone that needs to ask, a long, long time.  Not that the world needs yet another GUI builder.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like [GMF](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/gmp/) to create a graphical editor that generates code.  Building something like this from scratch would take months or years depending on your skill level and the scope of what you need.